# How do I do git push with JGit?

Tags: git, jgit

I'm trying to build a Java application that allows users to use Git based repositories. I was able to do this from the command-line, using the following commands:

```
git init
<create some files>
git add .
git commit
git remote add <remote repository name> <remote repository URI>
git push -u <remote repository name> master
```

This allowed me to create, add and commit content to my local repository and push contents to the remote repository. 
I am now trying to do the same thing in my Java code, using JGit. I was able to easily do git init, add and commit using JGit API.

```java
Repository localRepo = new FileRepository(localPath);
this.git = new Git(localRepo);        
localRepo.create();  
git.add().addFilePattern(".").call();
git.commit().setMessage("test message").call();
```

Again, all of this works fine. I couldn't find any example or equivalent code for `git remote add` and `git push`. I did look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861881/jgit-cannot-find-a-tutorial-or-simple-example).

`testPush()` fails with the error message `TransportException: origin not found`. In the other examples I've seen https://gist.github.com/2487157 do `git clone` **before** `git push` and I don't understand why that's necessary.

Any pointers to how I can do this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will find in [`org.eclipse.jgit.test`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/tree/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test) all the example you need:

- [`RemoteconfigTest.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/RemoteConfigTest.java) uses [`Config`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Config.java):

  ```java
  config.setString("remote", "origin", "pushurl", "short:project.git");
  config.setString("url", "https://server/repos/", "name", "short:");
  RemoteConfig rc = new RemoteConfig(config, "origin");
  assertFalse(rc.getPushURIs().isEmpty());
  assertEquals("short:project.git", rc.getPushURIs().get(0).toASCIIString());
  ```
- [PushCommandTest.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommandTest.java) illustrates various push scenario, [using `RemoteConfig`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommandTest.java#L162).
  See [`testTrackingUpdate()`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/9c67f680c890f2d33b50e43f10bd992d4c72f1a3/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommandTest.java#L132) for a complete example pushing *an* tracking a remote branch.
  Extracts:

  ```java
  String trackingBranch = "refs/remotes/" + remote + "/master";
  RefUpdate trackingBranchRefUpdate = db.updateRef(trackingBranch);
  trackingBranchRefUpdate.setNewObjectId(commit1.getId());
  trackingBranchRefUpdate.update();

  URIish uri = new URIish(db2.getDirectory().toURI().toURL());
  remoteConfig.addURI(uri);
  remoteConfig.addFetchRefSpec(new RefSpec("+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/"
      + remote + "/*"));
  remoteConfig.update(config);
  config.save();


  RevCommit commit2 = git.commit().setMessage("Commit to push").call();

  RefSpec spec = new RefSpec(branch + ":" + branch);
  Iterable<PushResult> resultIterable = git.push().setRemote(remote)
      .setRefSpecs(spec).call();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I did look at PushCommandTest.java but didn't understand enough to use it. I will try it out and give an update. Thanks again.

Comment: Tried it now and it worked great! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 41):

The easiest way is to use the JGit Porcelain API:

```java
    Git git = Git.open(localPath); 

    // add remote repo:
    RemoteAddCommand remoteAddCommand = git.remoteAdd();
    remoteAddCommand.setName("origin");
    remoteAddCommand.setUri(new URIish(httpUrl));
    // you can add more settings here if needed
    remoteAddCommand.call();

    // push to remote:
    PushCommand pushCommand = git.push();
    pushCommand.setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("username", "password"));
    // you can add more settings here if needed
    pushCommand.call();
```

Comment: Nice alternative to my (5 years old) answer. +1

Comment: What is the setName("origin") exactly doing?

Comment: Sets the name for the new remote repository added, similarly as you pass name while calling `git remote add [name] [uri]` from the terminal.

Comment: How would I push code like this, but to a specific branch?

Comment: This doesnt work for me . i get `org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException:` . I created the repository first and then i ran my java code to upload the files. its not working