# JGit create new local branch and push to remote (branch does not exist on remote)

Tags: java, git, git-branch, jgit, git-checkout

I'm working on an ANT task that calls some java that uses JGit to create a new branch on a git repository and push it to remote. I'm using JGit 2.1.0.

Here's the code:

```
CreateBranchCommand bcc;
CheckoutCommand checkout;
Git git;

try {
    Repository repo = new FileRepositoryBuilder().readEnvironment().findGitDir(src).build();
    git = new Git(repo);

    bcc = git.branchCreate();
    checkout = git.checkout();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new BuildException("Could not access repository " + src, e);
}

try {
        bcc.setName(branch)
            .setUpstreamMode(SetupUpstreamMode.SET_UPSTREAM)
            .setStartPoint("origin/" + branch)
            .setForce(force)
            .call();

        checkout.setName(branch);
        checkout.call();
}
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new BuildException("Could not checkout repository " + src, e);
}
```

The *src* variable is set to the path of the git repo (which has already been cloned). 
The *branch* variable is set to: **release_2_0_2**
The *force* variable is set to: **true** or **false** (with both I have this issue).

There is a separate ANT task afterward to do the push.

When running the above code an exception is caught in the 2nd catch:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref origin/release_2_0_2 can not be resolved
```

The issue seems to be with `setStartPoint("origin/" + branch)` If I hard code this to "origin/master" it works. The new branch is created. I'm simply trying to create a new branch locally and then push it to the remote. I was using https://stackoverflow.com/a/12928374/1860867 as an example.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how the CreateBranchCommand should be used, all the examples I've seen are setting the startpoint to `"origin/" + branch`.
Any suggestions/clarification would be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `setStartPoint()` to specify what the new branch should be based upon. The commit to which `setStartPoint` points will be the initial commit for the new branch.

If the start point isn't explicitly specified, it defaults to `HEAD`. Please see the Git documentation for more details: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

Hence the start point must exist - which the remote branch you are referring to clearly does not.

`setUpstreamMode()` isn't useful either if you are about to create a new branch. It is meant to configure *tracking* when you create a local branch for an existing remote branch. But since you don't have a remote branch yet there is no need to call `setUpstreamMode`.

Once you have created a local branch, use the `PushCommand` to publish it to the remote.

```java
git.push()
    .setRemote("origin")
    .setRefSpecs(new RefSpec("release_2_0_2:release_2_0_2"))
    .call();
```

The above lines push the `release_2_0_2` branch to the already known remote `origin` (the one you have cloned from).

The post [How do I do git push with JGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446842/how-do-i-do-git-push-with-jgit) has more details on how to push with JGit.

Comment: Thanks for the info and clarifications. I think the problem was the code I was trying to use was only meant to work with existing remote branches. I can just use a flag to indicate that the branch does not exist on the remote, and then use your logic.

Comment: Glad it helped. I find it sometimes helpful to write down to sequence of native Git commands that are necessary to achieve the goal and then _translate_ them into JGit API calls.