# How to commit and push to an existing branch using Jgit

Tags: jgit

Need help in pushing files to an existing branch using Jgit.
I tried:

```java
git.checkout().setName(existingBranchName).call();
git.add().addFilePattern(fileName).call();
git.commit().setMessage("commit message").call();
git.push().setRemote("origin").setCredentialProvider(credentials).call();
```

Not getting any exceptions but the commit is not pushed to that branch.

Comment: The `PushCommand` returns a `PushResult` that you can inspect to see what the command did.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do git push with JGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446842/how-do-i-do-git-push-with-jgit) I think you didn't set a remote.

Comment: Tried adding remote still no changes to the remote repo and there is no error also

Comment: Have you tried out the idea of RüdigerHerrmann?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it returned Iterable<PushResult> didn't get exactly what I have to found. Could you provide small code snippet If possible